# Meteor Cloud Log: "The container is being stopped because it has failed too many health checks."

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, cpu

Specs:
I am hosting a Meteor Application on Meteor Cloud using a Quad Container (4GB Memory and 4 ECUs CPU)

About the App:
The Meteor app is built by a framework called Empirica. It is meant for experiment applications. I made some custom changes such as some functions in the server side that assign connections and neighbors for each player.

Problems:
Hosting and deploying all have been a fine process. But when I do start a game and having about 12-15 connections to my application. I start to see the app's CPU usage constantly being at 100% (Or close to that). Whenever they all finished submitting some answers, the functions in my server starts running. However, it will only run for abit and then throw me this error:

0m9db 2023-06-27 11:51:10-04:00Application process starting, version 1
8bv7s 2023-06-27 11:51:23-04:00The container is being stopped due to a change in container type.
8bv7s 2023-06-27 11:51:23-04:00Application exited with signal: terminated
app 2023-06-27 11:51:47-04:00The app is unavailable, this is not a Galaxy issue, you should analyze your app, read more here https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/container-environment.html#unhealthy
98rtc 2023-06-27 11:52:10-04:00Application process starting, version 1
98rtc 2023-06-27 11:53:36-04:00The container is being stopped due to a change in container type.
98rtc 2023-06-27 11:53:37-04:00Application exited with signal: terminated
51b90 2023-06-27 11:54:16-04:00Application process starting, version 1
wrznq 2023-06-27 11:54:21-04:00Application process starting, version 1
0m9db 2023-06-27 11:55:15-04:00The container is being stopped due to a change in container type.
0m9db 2023-06-27 11:55:16-04:00Application exited with signal: terminated

I think it is because the server stayed at a 100% CPU usage (Or very close to that) for too long while the tasks is being handled. Therefore, causing the container health check to fail. Does anyone have experience with this and might have any idea on approaching this issue? The memory usage seems very low by the way.

Meteor documentation suggests two ways to scale my app. (See documentation link below)
https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/scaling.html

First is Vertical Scaling, which is increasing the container size when the task within my container requires more CPU.
Second is Horizontal Scaling, which is to handle a sudden increases in usage of traffic of my application.

It only makes more sense to increase the container size in my opinion (correct me if I am wrong).

Please help and suggest the approaches I should take from here. Thank you!